# Any specific reason why the kernel I compiled was an older version than the default kernel?

Tags: linux

the default kernel is 5.0.0-29-generic and the kernel I compiled is 4.15.0-58-generic.[image]

Comment: you chose the kernel version to compile, didn't you?

Comment: Please explain what steps you took to compile the kernel and/or link to what guide you followed to do so. (In short, it's because you compiled an older version — but without knowing the steps you're taking, we can't tell you what to change to get a newer version).

Comment: I have no idea. Why did you do it?

Comment: Where did you get the source?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a choice of kernel for Ubuntu 80. You need to tell it which one you want. One of them will be the default (probably the one that you got).

Install the correct source package, and try again.